# Is apiary.io available as non-hosted solution?

Tags: api-design, apiary.io, api-doc

Can apiary.io be used as a purely private on-premise solution as opposed to a hosted solution that is offered?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't appear so. Here's the press release from Oracle regarding the acquisition of Apiary:

https://www.oracle.com/corporate/acquisitions/apiary/index.html

It states:
"Apiary’s pioneering APIFlow solution provides the framework and tools for developing application programming interfaces (APIs) that share enterprise services and data and help create modern, cloud-based applications and experiences."